# Is 32013 a drop-in replacement for 3651?

Tags: technic, compatibility

In my old sets there are many 3651 parts that are broken.

[image: 3651]

As far as I remember, these sets do not use studs on the piece. Per [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2901/9417), new piece with the same function is 32013:

[image: 32013]

Can I just buy some of 32013 and use it everywhere instructions tell me to use 3651? Is it supposed to just fit? I could try to build 3651 but I'm afraid I'll   break it  again.

Comment: Can't think of anything why the 32013 would not fit as replacement, except when the studs would be used and although I also can't immediately name a set where they were used, I have a feeling that there are some.
The 32013 looks to me sturdier, the technic bush shaped part of 3651 is prone to cracking (like the technic bushes themselves)
I agree with the answer you refer to that the redesign happened because of the introduction of the new angular connectors.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve I was afraid that lengths might not be the same. I can't find technical drawings of them. "Prone to cracking" - yes, exactly :(

Comment: Besides the studs there is another difference that may affect the interchangeability: the 24 tooth gear next to its leg would intersect with the newer one.

Comment: @BalazsToth I posted CW answer, feel free and invited to add to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dimensions are, respectively:

- 3651 - [0.8cm x 1.6cm x 1.1cm](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-technic-connector-pin-bush-with-2-studs-3651)
- 32013 - [0.8cm x 1.6cm x 0.8cm](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-angle-connector-1-32013)

Distance between one axle and end of another also did not change. So for most builds it should work.

Incompatibilities include:

- Obvious lack of studs
- Use as in [Lego Technic Universal Set 8034](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8034-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) as a locking mechanism for lift system, as seen on the box:

  [image: Part of 8034 box]
- *This answer was posted as Community Wiki, please add incompatibilities if you know them*

Comment: Yes! The old part can be used as a "lock" or "stop" to prevent gears turning, and it works because of the flared edge. The new one (32013) does not have this, so you might have to improvise a bit.