# Can you help me identify this 2x2 modified brick?

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to identify this brick. I believe it is a genuine Lego brick. It doesn't appear to have a part number, but does have a '7' printed on the underside of the brick. It came from a large box of mixed Lego, so I'm not able to narrow down what set(s) it came from. I've tried identifying it on BrickLink, but without success. Thanks.

[[image]]

Comment: see [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2899/10369)...

Comment: Yes! That is the part. Thanks - please add this as an answer so I can mark it correct.